# Compile Time Assertion is Unreliable?

Tags: c++, static-assert

I am going through the first chapters of the book "Modern C++ Design". In particular, compile time assertions. I have some problem with the following code:

```
template<bool> struct CompileTimeChecker
{
  CompileTimeChecker(...) {}
};

template<> struct CompileTimeChecker<false> {};

#define STATIC_CHECK(expr, msg)\
{\
  struct ERROR_##msg {ERROR_##msg() {}};\
  CompileTimeChecker<((expr) != 0)>(ERROR_##msg());\
}

int main()
{
  STATIC_CHECK(0, MessageNull);
  STATIC_CHECK(1, MessageOne);
}
```

This doesn't raise a compile time error for g++ 7.4.0 and clang++ 6.0.0. However, the following code does raise an error (as expected):

```
template<bool> struct CompileTimeChecker
{
  CompileTimeChecker(...) {}
};

template<> struct CompileTimeChecker<false> {};

#define STATIC_CHECK(expr, msg)\
{\
  struct ERROR_##msg {ERROR_##msg(int i) {i;}};\
  CompileTimeChecker<((expr) != 0)>(ERROR_##msg(0));\
}

int main()
{
  STATIC_CHECK(0, MessageNull);
  STATIC_CHECK(1, MessageOne);
}
```

The only difference in the second code is the usage of a constructor with parameters.

---

The expected error message in both cases is:

- g++: `no matching function for call to ‘CompileTimeChecker<false>::CompileTimeChecker(main()::ERROR_MessageNull)`
- clang++: `no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'ERROR_MessageNull' to 'CompileTimeChecker<(0 != 0)>'`

Comment: Why not [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)?

Comment: Also, it should be `CompileTimeChecker<(expr)>`, not `CompileTimeChecker<(expr != 0)>`, because this is a macro.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Mostly because "Modern C++ Design"  is no longer modern. It predates C++11 and `static_assert`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the *most vexing parse*.  The following statement:

```
CompileTimeChecker<expr>(Type());
```

is equivalent to

```
CompileTimeChecker<expr> Type();
```

which declares a function named `Type`.  You can work around the issue by using the `=` form of initialization:

```
CompileTimeChecker<expr> var = Type();
```

This way, it cannot be interpreted as a declaration.  You can also use the `{}` initialization since C++11.  On the other hand,

```
CompileTimeChecker<expr>(Type(0));
```

is an expression statement that creates an object as desired because `Type(0)` cannot possibly declare a function.

Since C++11, just use `static_assert`.

Comment: Yes, and also it's specifically allowed to have both a struct and a function with the same name in the same scope, for header compatibility with C.

Comment: The parentheses didn't fix it for me because `function((a))` is equal to `function(a)`. But you are right about the function/constructor ambiguity. Writing `CompileTimeChecker<expr>(Type{});` fixed it for me (i.e. using uniform initialization). Can you update your answer?

Comment: @L.F. `CompileTimeChecker<expr>((Type()));` is not working for me.

Comment: @image I am wrong.  I confused this case with another case of most vexing parse.  I have updated the answer.  Hope it doesn't vex us again!